# Missing required parameter for [Route: add-item] [URI: home/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]. error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

got a little bit problem here
im trying to make my button to put some product at my home page into the cart
here are some of my code

route

```
Route::get('/home/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'addItem'])->name("add-item");
```

controller

```
public function addItem($id)
{
    $produk = Jasa::find($id);
    $id_user = Auth::id();
    $cart_name = $produk->nama_jasa;
    $cart_harga = $produk->estimasi_harga;
    $cart = Cart::create([
        'user_id' => $id_user,
        'name' => $cart_name,
        'harga' => $cart_harga,
    ]);
    $cart->save();
    return back();
}
```

blade

```
@foreach ($jasas as $jasa)
    <div class="desainFurnitur" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="300">
        <img src="{{ asset('storage/ListJasa/' . $adminListJasa[0]->filename) }}">
        <div class="text-listjasa">
            <h3>{{ $adminListJasa[0]->heading }}</h3>
            <p type="hidden" class="text-center font-weight-bold card-text">{{$jasa->name}}</p>
        </div>
        <a href="{{ route('add-item',['id'=>$jasa->id] ) }}" class="btn btn-secondary">Add To Cart</a>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Id has value

Check First that `$jasa->id` it's not null.

Your route is

```
Route::get('/home/{id}', [HomeController::class, 'addItem'])->name("add-item");
```

The param `id` is required. When you pass `null` these type of error generate. So make sure that you are not passing `'id' => null`;

For testing purpose you can make these param optional like

```
Route::get('/home/{id?}', [HomeController::class, 'addItem'])->name("add-item");
```

And in method you need to write

```
public function addItem($id = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, Hope it will help you

```
{{route('add-item',$jasa->id)}}

or 

{{ route('add-item',[$jasa->id] ) }}
```

Comment: still have the same error:( thank you for replying

Comment: dd($jasa->id)  // id get or not please check first ?

Comment: it works now got some typo :( , thank youu

Comment: We are glad that our solution helped you... :)

Answer (score 0):

First `dd($jasas);` and `dd($jasa)` to know where the id exists. The error is because the id is not getting added to the route..

Thank you